# Automate an SSIS query for a table name having a month and year timestamp

Tags: sql-server, date, ssis, sql-server-2016

I have a database in which a table names are associated with month and year numbers ex: datavalues_7_2017 for july, datavalues_8_2017 for august and so on.
I am using a query to retrieve certain values from the table.

```
SELECT o_key ,MIN(dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, time), 0)) as on_time
,MAX(dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, dateadd(hour, 1, time)), 0)) as off_time
,cast(time as date) as RDNG_DT ,[repeated_hour],[value]
FROM [data_values_8_2017] 
WHERE value = 1 and o_key in (X,X,X,X...) and cast(time as date) = cast(getdate() as date)
GROUP BY o_key,cast(time as date),repeated_hour,value
```

I am using SSIS package and using this query I am loading the result into another table.
Now this table datavalues_X_2017 is bound to change every month creating a new table, and my SSIS query should be pointing to the new table. 
Can someone suggest me a way where I can automate this processes.

Comment: Please close this question by clicking the checkmark next to the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create a stored procedure as a wrapper and have a date parameter passed to it as shown below. Call this procedure as part of your source.

If you do not want it as stored procedure, use the same logic and put the sql as a variable and in the expressions pass the month and year variable

```
create procedure dbo.usp_GetData
(
    @Date   datetime = null
)
as

if @Date is null
    set @Date = GETDATE()

declare @Month  int
        ,@Year  int
        ,@sql   nvarchar(max)

select  @Month = DATEPART(MONTH,@Date)
        ,@Year = DATEPART(YEAR,@Date)

set @sql ='
            select  o_key 
                    ,MIN(dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, time), 0)) as on_time 
                    ,MAX(dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, dateadd(hour, 1, time)), 0)) as off_time 
                    ,cast(time as date) as RDNG_DT 
                    ,[repeated_hour],[value]
            from    [data_values_'+CAST(@Month AS VARCHAR(2))+'_'+CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR(4))+'] 
            where   value = 1 
                        and o_key in (
                            X,X,X,X...
                            ) 
                        and cast(time as date) = cast(getdate() as date)
            group by o_key
                    ,cast(time as date)
                    ,repeated_hour
                    ,value
                    ';
exec sp_executesql  @sql;

go
```

Comment: Thank you Vkarthik, the solution helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

Get dynamic SQL with Variable Expressions the following way:

- Create a String variable *DateSuffux* which will be filled with your datevalue like `"7_2017"`
- Create a String variable *SQLQuery* with properties `EvaluateAsExpression=true` and define the following Expression for it

  ```
  "SELECT o_key ,...,[repeated_hour],[value] FROM [data_values_" +  
  @[User::DateSuffix] + "] WHERE ... "
  ```
- Specify variable *SQLQuery* as a source for your Data Source or SQL Query task

You are done.
This variable expression substitutes result of the expression when the *SQLQuery* variable is used. The expression itself injects contents of *DateSuffix* string variable into a query text.